# Problems parsing fields from multipart with GridForm / FormidableJS

Tags: android, ios, express, formidable

I have an expressJS server running. I am POSTING multipart form-data to the server, and parsing this with GridForm (which again, correct me if I am wrong, is an extension of FormidableJS). This seems to work fine when posting from a web-form, or Postman etc., however, when I try to post from my Android app or IOS app, there is a strange issue. Sometimes it works fine, and then, even though I do no changes in the app code, no **fields** are parsed. The **files** are however allways parsed, so it is clear that the POST actually comes through. Anyone have any ideas of what this problem can be?

Comment: Great question. This has been irritating me as well.